# Free License for commercial Use

Tags: cordova, mapbox

I want to develop hybrid crossplatform mobile application using visual studio and cordova. I found a great plugin from Telerik:

http://plugins.telerik.com/cordova/plugin/mapbox

On that site, it says you have to get an API-Key from

https://www.mapbox.com/pricing/#

My Application will never exceed the 50'000 mobile users that are free with the starter license, so can i use that license for commercial purposes? Did i miss something?

I dont know a lot about licensing...

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: *Commercial apps require payment to access, are behind a firewall, or are for internal business use.* If you are making a commercial app you need to pay for the software.

Comment: yeah my app would be behind a paywall. why do you think id need to pay for it if my uses are within the standard license?

Answer (score 0):

I have built a mobile / cordova app that uses Google MAPs that include all the features that Telerik shows.You can do it for free.

There are some Cordova plugins over Google Maps, but IMO you do not need those or any Cordova Plugin for Maps. Just use the standard Google Map API for HTML.  That way you can test all you code using Localhost vs. deploying to the device.

Go to Google Developers, Create an account and get a Map API key.

https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/#details

Here is a Simple HTML sample from Google. 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-overlays

Comment: if i use standard api for html it wont be able to use native features like gps service and stuff, but i need those

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I use a Corodova plug to get GPS data and feed that to maps for my purpose. It sounds like you are doing something more advanced.

Comment: i want to use offline data and do polygons and stuff and the ability to see your own exact location

open street maps is better for the offline stuff afaik, and they have this mapbox cordova plugin so thats why im wondering about the licensing...